# How to port a linux wxWidgets app to Windows + Mac

Tags: windows, linux, macos, wxwidgets, porting

I'm trying to port an app built with Code::Blocks in Linux (Ubuntu) to Windows.
There was an option in configure.sh to compile Windows and Mac versions, but then errors were thrown and it didn't work.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Can you paste the error messages?

Comment: @Blender It said `Windows.h wasn't found.` I think that is because I run a Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

You should surround all your platform-dependent code inside #if defiend(__WXMSW__) ... #endif directives (other platforms have their own preprocessor vars). You can take a look at wxWidgets's source code and see how the problem is solved there.

```
//Common code
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
    // Windows code goes here
#else if defined(__WXGTK__)
    // Linux code goes here
#else if defined(__WXMAC__)
    // Mac code goes here
#else
    // Code for other platforms
#endif
// Common code
```

Comment: There's one problem. I don't have any platform independent code, I'd just like to have all my code working on other platforms, like Audacity.